# How to copy a SQL Azure Database within same Azure DB server? Possible in MS SQL Server Mgt Studio?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I want to make a copy of my SQL Azure DB ie "DevDB".

I understand that I need to run:

```
CREATE DATABASE Dev-DB AS COPY OF Test-DB;
```

from Master DB of destination server, ie same server,

I create a DB connection by logging into my the Azure DB within MS SQL Server Mgt Studio using my Azure DB Server user/password.

I open a "new query window" of the Azure Sql Server, choose Master and then run the above code. Sadly I just get:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

Thoughts??

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried enclosing the names in brackets? e.g. [Dev-DB]

Comment: Just tried, and it works. Huge thanks. What is the problem without []. I just followed MS's documentation....

Comment: JuneT, can you please add this comment as an answer, with a little bit longer explanation, so the question can properly be marked as answered.